# referesh js file from another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

**jquery**

I am using the following to load js file from another js file.

```
$.getScript("js/keys.js");
```

Due to ajax call, I remove some event handler from **key.js**. so for this purpose I use the above mentioned code to reload the **keys.js**, so that the even handler that I have removed then to be available. It is working fine;but

I want that when I recall **key.js** , it reload only that piece of code that is not in cache, because it reset value of variables.

Comment: "I want that when I recall key.js" you want what?

Comment: I want when I call $.getScript("js/keys.js"), It not reload all the key.js file. but load only area that I have removed! because when I call $.getScript("js/keys.js") key.js file still available with variables ,but non of the event handler is available because I removed

Comment: Since we are not working with you.. you should be more clear with the question if you want answers.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to not reload the **key.js** file, just active/ recall event handler that you have removed.

instead of write the following code:

```
$.getScript("js/keys.js");
```

replace it like :(one Example)

```
$("#name").click(function(){

});
```

Hope it will help you.